# Open Helm buffer vertically permanently

Tags: helm

Helm opens buffer using a vertical split by default.

[image]

I want the Helm buffer to open using a horizontal split by default.

[image]

I can use `C-t` (`helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows`) to manually toggle the position, but how can I make this change permanent?

Comment: How about `(setq helm-split-window-default-side 'right)` (defaults to 'below)?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it. The documentation says "The default side to display `helm-buffer'.", but it does not work for me.

Comment: Alright, I have found the source. The above sexp (suggested by @xuchunyang) would work. But the problem is with popwin, enabling popwin seems to override the helm settings. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details: the problem was I was using `(push '("*Help*" :regexp t) popwin:special-display-config)` in `popwin`. This matches helm buffers.